# Increased loading time of two websites sharing one database

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access

Our main website remotely accessed the database of our other website which is on a different domain hosting. My problem is our main website is very slow in loading a page while the second website is not experiencing the problem of our main website(database is hosted on our second website).

Why we're experiencing this problem on our main website?
What would be the possible reasons?
What would be the possible solutions for this?

Edit:
We just transfer the other domain to the same hosting of our main website. 
Maybe the problem is the database authentication process between two hosting.

Comment: So Website A is slow when loading data from Database in environment B but Website B (also environment B) doesn't have the same issue? Isn't it simply that the database transport times are longer as it's in a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very wide question - I can only give general advice.

I'd start by making sure the slow website is properly written. Run the website on a controlled development environment, with a copy of your production database, and use a tool like Apache JMeter to subject it to load; make sure it is "fast" in that environment. "Fast" is a movable concept, but I'd be expecting to see sub-second response times up to hundreds of concurrent users. 
If the site is slow in this context, it will be slow on production; find out where the bottleneck is, tune, optimize etc.

If that isn't the problem, I'd replicate that setup with the other website connecting to the same database, and throw load at both sites simultaneously. You might just have reached the scalability limits of the system, and you may be seeing performance issues related to that - unlikely if the first website responds quickly and the second doesn't, but it's possible you're seeing deadlocks or other concurrency issues.

If the website behaves well on "perfect" infrastructure, but not in production, you need to work out what the issue is on production. The best way is to use a profiler on the production environment; this might mean creating a copy of the website which isn't publicly accessible, and installing the profiler there. XDebug works nicely for PHP.
The profiler will show you where your application slows down; it could be in the PHP code, it could be in the authentication section, it could be executing the SQL queries.

Once the profiler tells you where the problem is, you can work out how to fix it.

However, as a rule of thumb, running database queries outside a single network cage is a terrible idea; it's not secure, it exposes your database queries to arbitrary internet performance problems, and it eats into your bandwidth allocation. It's not really to do with the domain in the sense of "www.company.com" - one hosting environment can run multiple domains - but if you're routing your database traffic over the public internet, you give up any control over performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to use the xdebug.. tnx for the advice :)